# Pytorch resnet with zero loss

Tags: pytorch, resnet

I am training a Pytorch Resnet model for image segmentation. I have two classes and I am training with RGB images and corresponding binary masks. While my accuracy values are very high (~0.99), my loss values for both training and validation are zeroes throughout all epochs. How can I fix this issue?

```py
#we do the spatial transformations first, and afterwards do any color augmentations
img_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomCrop(size=(patch_size,patch_size),pad_if_needed=True), #these need to be in a reproducible order, first affine transforms and then color
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size=patch_size),
    transforms.RandomRotation(180),
    transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0, contrast=0, saturation=0, hue=.5),
    transforms.RandomGrayscale(),
    transforms.ToTensor()
    ])


mask_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomCrop(size=(patch_size,patch_size),pad_if_needed=True), #these need to be in a reproducible order, first affine transforms and then color
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size=patch_size,interpolation=PIL.Image.NEAREST),
    transforms.RandomRotation(180),
    ])




dataset={}
dataLoader={}
for phase in phases: #now for each of the phases, we're creating the dataloader
                     #interestingly, given the batch size, i've not seen any improvements from using a num_workers>0
    dataset[phase]=Dataset(f"/content/{dataname}_{phase}.pytable", img_transform=img_transform , mask_transform = mask_transform ,edge_weight=edge_weight)
    dataLoader[phase]=DataLoader(dataset[phase], batch_size=batch_size, 
                                shuffle=True, num_workers=0, pin_memory=True)
    

optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters()) 
nclasses = dataset["train"].numpixels.shape[1]
class_weight=dataset["train"].numpixels[1,0:2] #don't take ignored class into account here
class_weight = torch.from_numpy(1-class_weight/class_weight.sum()).type('torch.FloatTensor').to(device)

print(class_weight) #show final used weights, make sure that they're reasonable before continouing
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = class_weight, ignore_index = ignore_index ,reduce=False) #reduce = False makes sure we get a 2D output instead of a 1D "summary" value


for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    #zero out epoch based performance variables 
    print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
    print('-' * 10)
    all_acc = {key: 0 for key in phases} 
    all_loss = {key: torch.zeros(0).to(device) for key in phases}
    cmatrix = {key: np.zeros((2,2)) for key in phases}

    for phase in phases: #iterate through both training and validation states

        if phase == 'train':
            model.train()  # Set model to training mode
        else: #when in eval mode, we don't want parameters to be updated
            model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode
        running_loss = 0.0
        running_corrects = 0
        for ii , (X, y, y_weight) in enumerate(dataLoader[phase]): #for each of the batches
            optim.zero_grad()
            X = X.to(device)  # [Nbatch, 3, H, W]
            y_weight = y_weight.type('torch.FloatTensor').to(device)
            y = y.type('torch.LongTensor').to(device)  # [Nbatch, H, W] with class indices (0, 1)
            with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'): #dynamically set gradient computation, in case of validation, this isn't needed
                                                            #disabling is good practice and improves inference time

                prediction = model_ft(X)  # [N, Nclass]
                y = y[:, 0,0]
                loss = criterion(prediction, y)
                print(loss)
                _, preds = torch.max(X, 1)
                preds = preds[:,0,0]
                if phase=="train": #in case we're in train mode, need to do back propogation
                    
                    loss.mean().backward()
                    optim.step()
                

                

            running_loss += loss.data[0]
            running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == y)
        epoch_loss = running_loss / len(dataLoader[phase].dataset)
        epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / len(dataLoader[phase].dataset)

        print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))

        # deep copy the model
        if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
           best_acc = epoch_acc
           best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
        if phase == 'val':
           val_acc_history.append(epoch_acc)

    print()
```